# Recursive call to IObservable in Windows Phone 7 application using Rx

Tags: windows-phone-7, reactive-programming

We have a Windows Phone 7 application which uses a set of 3 service methods using Reactive Extensions, defined as follows:

```
public static class ServiceClient
{
    public static IObservable<string> LookupImage(byte[] image) {...}

    public static IObservable<XDocument> GetDefinition(string id) {...}

    public static IObservable<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> GetFiles(string id, string[] fileNames) {...}                
}
```

We need the WP7 application to keep calling `LookupImage` in the above client (each time with different set of `byte[] image` data) until the returned `IObservable<string>` is nonempty. After we get the `Observable` string we have to call `GetDefinition` and `GetFiles` methods (in that order).

The calls to `LookupImage` should happen as often as the service response is returned as opposed to being controlled by a timer as it will vary depending on network connection speed and we need to be able to send as many of these as possible.

I'd appreciate any pointers to what might be a solution to the above. As a start I have the following

```
private void RunLookupAndRenderLogic()
{   
   byte[] imageBytes = GetImageBytes();

   // There are some cases where the image was not 'interesting' enough in which case GetImageBytes() returns null
   if (pictureBytes != null)
   {
      // Where we have image data, send this to LookupImage service method
      var markerLookup = ServiceClient.LookupImage(imageBytes);

      markerLookup.Subscribe(id =>      
        {
                       // If the id is empty, we need to call this again.
                       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                       {
                            ???
                       }

                       // If we have an id, call GetDefinition and GetFiles methods of the service. No further calls to LookupImage should take place.
                       RenderLogic(id);   
     });
  }
  else
   // If no interesting image was returned, try again
   RunRecognitionAndRenderLogic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I get this wrong, but if I understand it correctly you want to Retry the call to LookupImage with the exact same argument,  until it returns a value?

A naive way of solving this would be to simply call repeat and then take(1):

```
ServiceClient.LookupImage(imageBytes)
    .Repeat()
    .Take(1)
    .Subscribe(id =>  ....);
```

However as [Rx is single threaded by default](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#RxIsSingleThreadedByDefault), there is no point in this context that allows us to inject our disposal call (implicit from the Take(1)-->OnComplete()-->Auto disposal of subscription).

You can dodge this by offering some breathing space between subsequent re-subscriptions by using the CurrentThread Scheduler.

```
Observable.Defer(()=>
    ServiceClient.LookupImage(imageBytes)
                 .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    )
    .Repeat()
    .Take(1)
    .Subscribe(id =>  ....);
```

There are other ways of achieving this with some good understanding of Rx and some creativity. (Most I would imagine a Scheduler)

To give you some inspriation check out [the chapter on Scheduling and Threading](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html). It covers recursion and building your own iterator which is effectively what you are trying to do.

Full code sample:

```
private void RunLookupAndRenderLogic()
{   
    byte[] imageBytes = GetImageBytes();

    // There are some cases where the image was not 'interesting' enough in which case GetImageBytes() returns null
    if (pictureBytes != null)
    {
        // Where we have image data, send this to LookupImage service method
        var subscription = Observable
        .Defer(()=>
            ServiceClient.LookupImage(imageBytes)
                     .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
        )
        .Where(id=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        .Repeat()
        .Take(1)
        .Subscribe(id =>      
        {
           // If we have an id, call GetDefinition and GetFiles methods of the service. No further calls to LookupImage should take place.
           RenderLogic(id);   
        });

        //TODO: You dont offer any way to cancel this (dispose of the suscription). 
        //This means you could loop forever :-(
    }
    else
    {
        // If no interesting image was returned, try again
        RunRecognitionAndRenderLogic();
    }
}
```

(Disclosure: I am the author of IntroToRx.com)